# Necessary to assume $f\in C^\infty$ in this Fourier transform problem?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Consider the following problem. Is the hypothesis that $f\in C^\infty$ necessary, or could we weaken it and assume just that $f$ is continuous?

> Let $\hat f$ denote the Fourier transform of the function $f$ on
>   $\mathbb R$. Suppose $f\in C^\infty$ and $\|\hat f(\xi) \|_2 \le
>  \alpha$, $ \|\xi^{1+\epsilon} \hat f\|_2 \le \beta$, for some
>   $\epsilon >0$. Find a bound on $\| f(x)\|_\infty$ in terms of
>   $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\epsilon$.

Proposed Solution (assuming only that $f$ is continuous): It suffices to bound $\|\hat f\|_1$ in terms of $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\epsilon$. Once we know $\hat f \in L_1$, we can write

$$F^{-1}\hat f(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb R} \hat f(\xi)e^{2\pi i\xi}\ d\xi,$$

since the $L^2$ Fourier inverse definition and $L^1$ Fourier inverse definition agree on functions in $L^1\cap L^2$. Since $F^{-1}\hat f(\xi)$ is continuous, and $f(x)$ is the unique member of that $L^2$ equivalence class that is continuous, we have

$$f(x)= \int_{\mathbb R} \hat f(\xi)e^{2\pi i\xi}\ d\xi.$$

Then our original bound on $\| \hat f\|_1$ gives a bound on $\|f\|_\infty$.

For the bound on $\|\hat f\|_1$, split $\hat f$ as $\hat f=\hat f\chi_{[-1,1]} + f\chi_{[-1,1]^c}$. On the piece $[-1,1]$, we note $[-1,1]$ is a finite measure space, so the $L^1$ norm is bounded by a constant times the $L^2$ norm (by the usual Cauchy-Schwarz argument). On $[-1,1]^c$, write $\hat f = \xi^{-(1+\epsilon)}(\xi^{1+\epsilon}\hat f)$ and again apply Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: What I find interesting is that (seemingly) you could get away with a weaker statement: replace $\xi^{1+\varepsilon}$ with $\xi^{\frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon}$. Assuming your analysis is correct - which it seems to be.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yes, indeed. I'm inclined to just say the problem is not very tightly constructed, but given the rate at which I make errors, I thought it was wise to check...

Comment: It definitely does seem to be rather loosely put together. Either that or the authors had something very different (read: very laborious) in mind.